# Code base build on 32bit Ubuntu 12.04 on x86_64 bit machine is taking more time

Tags: 12.04

I have a code base to be built. I am building it on a 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running on a high end machine (Intel i7, 16 GB RAM, HT enabled). But it is taking more time compared to the time taken on Intel Dual Core machine. It is taking almost double time.

Both the machines have x86_64 processor. High end machine is quad core with HT enabled an 16GB RAM, the other one is a dual core with 4GB RAM.

My expectation was, the build on high end machine should have taken half the time, but it is taking double time.

Please let me know what is the reason for this. Any pointers to debug this issue will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you please elaborate more on what and how you are building?

Comment: I am building Tizen source code base using GBS build environment. More information available on below URL    https://source.tizen.org/documentation/articles/creating-tizen-platform-image-scratch-through-local-build                     The same source code base runs faster on the dual core machine where as it is taking double the time on this machine with 16GB RAM and i7 quad core machine. The cat /proc/cpuinfo shows 8 cores (as HT is enabled on the system). But why still the build time is more is what I am not able to understand. Really appreciate any help in debugging this issue.

Comment: More info on the system configuration: HT enabled machine: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz, HT enabled, RAM 16GB, HDD is 1TB. Dual Core machine: Intel (R) Pentium (R) G630 @ 2.70GHz, 4GB RAM, 250GB HDD. Tried running sysbench tool for disk IOs and noticed that to create test files of 8GB the high end HT enabled system is taking 1Hr where as the dual core machine is taking 8mins. is this because the high end machine has 1TB of HDD (signel partition)? Does Ubuntu run fine on single partitioned 1TB HDD? Please do the needful. Thanks in advance.